# How does GraphicsPath.AddArc use the startAngle and sweepAngle parameters?

Tags: c#, graphics, geometry, gdi+, trigonometry

I am trying to use System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddArc to draw an arc of an ellipse starting at 0 degrees and sweeping to 135 degrees.

The issue I am running in to is that for an ellipse, the arc drawn does not match up with what I would expect.

For example, the following code generates the image below. The green circles are where I would expect the end points of the arc to be using the formula for a point along an ellipse. My formula works for circles but not for ellipses.

Does this have something to do with polar versus Cartesian coordinates?

```
    private PointF GetPointOnEllipse(RectangleF bounds, float angleInDegrees)
    {
        float a = bounds.Width / 2.0F;
        float b = bounds.Height / 2.0F;

        float angleInRadians = (float)(Math.PI * angleInDegrees / 180.0F);

        float x = (float)(( bounds.X + a ) + a * Math.Cos(angleInRadians));
        float y = (float)(( bounds.Y + b ) + b * Math.Sin(angleInRadians));

        return new PointF(x, y);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle circleBounds = new Rectangle(250, 100, 500, 500);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, circleBounds);

        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath circularPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        circularPath.AddArc(circleBounds, 0.0F, 135.0F);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Red, circularPath);

        PointF circlePoint = GetPointOnEllipse(circleBounds, 135.0F);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, new RectangleF(circlePoint.X - 5, circlePoint.Y - 5, 10, 10));

        Rectangle ellipseBounds = new Rectangle(50, 100, 900, 500);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, ellipseBounds);

        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath ellipticalPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        ellipticalPath.AddArc(ellipseBounds, 0.0F, 135.0F);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Blue, ellipticalPath);

        PointF ellipsePoint = GetPointOnEllipse(ellipseBounds, 135.0F);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Green, new RectangleF(ellipsePoint.X - 5, ellipsePoint.Y - 5, 10, 10));
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphicsPath.AddArc does exactly what you ask it to do -- it the arc up to a line projecting from the ellipse center, at an exact angle of 135 degrees clockwise from the x axis.

Unfortunately, this doesn't help when you're using the angle as a direct proportion of a pie chart slice you want to draw. To find out the angle B you need to use with AddArc, given an angle A that works on a circle, in radians, use:

```
B = Math.Atan2(sin(A) * height / width, cos(A))
```

Where *width* and *height* are those of the ellipse.

In your sample code, try adding the following at the end of Form1_Paint:

```
ellipticalPath = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
ellipticalPath.AddArc(
    ellipseBounds,
    0.0F,
    (float) (180.0 / Math.PI * Math.Atan2(
        Math.Sin(135.0 * Math.PI / 180.0) * ellipseBounds.Height / ellipseBounds.Width,
        Math.Cos(135.0 * Math.PI / 180.0))));
e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, ellipticalPath);
```

The result should look as follows:
[alt text http://img216.imageshack.us/img216/1905/arcs.png](http://img216.imageshack.us/img216/1905/arcs.png)

Comment: Cool! That works. But I still don't understand why it works. What is the logic behind your calculation? Does this have anything to do with polar vs. Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: GetPointOnEllipse finds a point in two steps:

1. it finds a point on the circumference of a circle with R=1 at an angle A from the X axis, at (cos(A), sin(A))

2. it transforms the point with a stretch transform, to (w*cos(A), h*sin(A))

The stretch transform changes the angle! (imagine what the angle would be if we stretched the circle very wide)

To find the new angle B, note that tan(B)=y/x, and hence B=atan(y/x). To avoid dividing by zero, we'll use B=atan2(y,x)

As (x,y)=(w*cos(A), h*sin(A)), we get B=atan2(h*sin(A),w*cos(A))

Divide by w to get B=atan2(sin(A)*h/w,cos(A))

Makes sense?

Comment: I don't fully understand your statement: "The stretch transform changes the angle!". I can see from the output image that the angle is different. But what I am confused on is the formula for a point on an ellipse. The formula is x = a cos(theta), y = b sin(theta). Does the fact that it draws at a different point mean that the angle being measured is different from the angle being measured by AddArc? I found another thread on this subject. It seems to point to the issue having something to do with polar coords. http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/665773-drawarc-ellipse-geometry-repost

Comment: If we draw a line inclined at 45 degrees to the X axis, then for each point on that line, x=y, always, at all times -- wouldn't you say? We could draw that line on the screen, or on paper. What about theta=45, however? We know sin(45)=cos(45)=~0.707. For our ellipse, a cos(45)=b sin(45) if and only if a=b. If a>b then x>y, and therefore won't touch the 45 degrees line on the screen/paper. It's located somewhere to its right. That means that theta does not track the angle you are looking for on the screen. It's confusing because theta ranges between 0 and 360 like a circle (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) It's also confusing as theta IS the correct angle for precisely 4 points on the ellipse -- when the ellipse crosses the X and Y axes. But at all other points on the ellipse, theta is not the correct angle. AddArc does the right thing. When you tell it to end at 45 degrees, it precisely hits the 45 degrees line we drew. It ignores the fact that the arc is on the surface of an ellipse that can be described by a cos(theta),b sin(theta), or by any other formula for that matter.

Comment: I agree that AddArc is doing the right thing. Which leads me to believe that theta in the ellipse equation is not an angle measured from the center of the ellipse, or it would come up with the same point, correct? So what is theta in the ellipse equation?

Comment: Exactly -- that is correct. As for theta, you could say that it tracks the angle on a circle that is 3d-projected to the ellipse using orthographic projection.

Comment: +1 for being unlike the vast majority of random math-challenged folks and not only being able to do basic math but hitting geometry home runs with ease!

Answer (score 9):

[image]I was getting confused about how GraphicsPath.AddArc worked & I couldn't find any decent diagrams, so I drew one. Just in case anyone else has been suffering similarly! https://i.stack.imgur.com/50HBn.jpg

Comment: Hi ClareSubdery,
I don't know what was your environment when you made this.
But I try today, with my windows 10 PC, The start angle (in your picture) need to plus 180 more degrees.